# How can i solve ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, eclipse

I am getting this error, while everything is well imported.
I need some help to identify the source of this error.

```
  from tta.core.exception import TTAISOTPTimeoutError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tta'
```

This error is shown even though the program runs and execute flawless.
Strange, right?

```
from time import sleep
from tta.core import logger as Logger
from tta.runner import Runner
from tta.testcase import AdvancedTestCaseBase
from tta.testcase.testcase_base import ParameterInt
from tta.units.relay import Relay
```

Comment: Are you sure that `tta` is installed? May be run `pip freeze` to see if it is installed.

Comment: The program continues running after this error?

Comment: yes everything is installed. And yes also it continue running!